# Background of docked QDockWidget?

Tags: qt, qtstylesheets

I know when a `QDockWidget` is undocked it should be styled with `QMainWindow`.
I would like to style the background of the whole `QDockWidget` when it's docked to the `QMainWindow`...

How can I do it with stylesheets?

**EDIT**: So, I know how to style QMainWindow:

```
QMainWindow {
    background-color: red;
}
```

But I don't know how can I style "dockable windows" when they are docked, if I apply:

```
QDockWidget {
    background-color: green;
}
```

I get the green colored window, but how to style the background of a docked one? I tried:

```
QMainWindow QDockWidget {
    margin: 10px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

But does not work... it gets the same background as QMainWindow

Thanks

Comment: Could you please show what you have already tried?

Comment: Thanks demonplus, I have updated the main question. Do you understand the question now?

Comment: One option would be to exchange the stylesheet on dock/undock, see https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdockwidget.html#topLevelChanged

Comment: I don't have access to the code... I only can "play" at stylesheet level =(